# Deleting all non-required fields in table using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, attribute-table, fields-attributes, delete

In ArcGIS Pro I want to delete all non-required fields from a table using ModelBuilder. The number of fields will be variable since it will the product of multiple Union functions.

Is there a way to do this via Wildcard?

All the fields I want to keep start with `SignalV` followed by a number.

Comment: What does your model so far look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure model builder approach then use the Iterate Fields with wildcard `SignalV*` and feed is output into a Collects Value tool. Expose the output of Collects Value as a parameter. This becomes a sub-model feeding into the delete fields tool in the master model.